# Probability of 2 teams winning

Tags: probability

My 2 fav teams are in the 2 semi finals, 1 in each, what is the chance of one of my teams winning the final is it 50% or more?

One of my customers at work asked this to me today and I would love to get back to him with an answer (a correct one).

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It depends. If both teams have a very low probability of making it through the semis, then the chances of winning the final are very low.

Comment: You need to quantify the probabilities in some way. Are you assuming that all teams are equally good in some sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for your answer, yes all have an equal chance, so I had a 75% chance of one of my teams winning the final or is it 50%, we seem to have 2 answers?

Comment: The answer is a half...

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the matches are

A v B, C v D where your favourite teams are A and C

Now we need to define some probabilities

Let $P_1$ be the probability that A beats B.

Let $P_2$ be the probability that C beats D.

Let $P_3$ be the probability that A will beat D if they meet in the final.

Let $P_4$ be the probability that C will beat B if they meet in the final.

In order for one of your favourite teams to win you need either

- A to beat B, C to lose to D and A to win in the final.

$$P_1 \cdot (1 - P_2) \cdot P_3 $$

- A to lose to B, C to beat D and C to beat B in the final.

$$ (1 - P_1) \cdot P_2 \cdot P4 $$

- A to beat B and C to beat D, then we don't care about the final.

$$ P_1 \cdot P_2$$

As these possibilities are mutually exclusive we can just add them up

$$P_1 \cdot (1 - P_2) \cdot P_3 + (1 - P_1) \cdot P_2 \cdot P4 + P_1 \cdot P_2 $$

We can't go any further because we don't know $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ and $P_4$ but if we assume they are all 50% = $\dfrac{1}{2}$ then

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

[Assumption: in a match, each team has an equal chance of winning.]

Without calculating anything: by symmetry, each of the 4 teams has an equal chance of winning the final. So the probability that one of your favorite teams wins is 1/2.

---

In case you're not convinced: enumerate the 8 possible outcomes of the three matches, and you will see that each team wins the final in 2 of the 8 outcomes:

Suppose the semis are A vs B, C vs D. We can denote each outcome by the winner of the three games: for example, if A beats B, D beats C, and then D wins the final, we can denote it by ADD. Then the list of outcomes is ACA, ACC, ADA, ADD, BCB, BCC, BDB, BDD.

Answer (score 0):

You only care about whether one of your favourite teams wins.

There are three matches, let $S_1, S_2, F$ be either $0$ or $1$ representing the outcome of each match.

If $S_K = 1$ then one of your favourites wins that semi-final. If $F=1$, then the team that won the $S_2$ semi-final wins the final.

It is not hard to see that the boolean expression
$W(S_1,S_2,F) = \bar{F}{S_1} + F{S_2} $ is $1$ **iff** one of your teams wins the final (and zero otherwise). We want to compute $E[W]$.

I am assuming that there are no draws and that each match is independent, and each match has an equal probability of a win or loss. Hence each $(S_1,S_2,F) \in \{0,1\}^3$ is equally likely.

Since the events $\bar{F}{S_1}$,$ F{S_2}$ are mutually exclusive, we have
$E[W]= E[\bar{F}{S_1}]+E[F{S_2}]$, and since we assume independence, we have
$E[W]= E[\bar{F}]E[{S_1}]+E[F]E[{S_2}]$, from which we get
$E[W]= {1 \over 2} {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2} {1 \over 2} = {1 \over 2}$.